# ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::OracleEnhancedConnectionException "DESC tablename, does it exist?" error while running migrations for test setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, activerecord, rspec

I am trying to setup database in test environment. But I am not able to migrate the database

I looked on internet for hours. Even though this is a common problem, none of the solutions provided worked for me. Most common cause of the problem posted was wrong credentials could be posted in database.yml file. I checked that too. My databse.yml is correct.

To do this I the executed the rake

'rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test'

On executing the above command, it shows error as:

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::OracleEnhancedConnectionException: "DESC articles" failed; does it exist?
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.7.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/oci_connection.rb:231:in `rescue in describe'

Caused by:
OCIError: ORA-04043: object articles does not exist
metadata.c:175:in oci8lib_240.so
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/ruby-oci8-2.2.5/lib/oci8/metadata.rb:2053:in `block in describe_table'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/ruby-oci8-2.2.5/lib/oci8/metadata.rb:2052:in `times'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/ruby-oci8-2.2.5/lib/oci8/metadata.rb:2052:in `describe_table'
```

Please help.

Thanks inadvance.

Comment: delete your schema.rb file and run the same command

Comment: It can be related to inheritance (depends on your model). If yes, try to add 'self.abstract_class = true' in your articles model.

Comment: Is deleting the schema or adding the line in model necessary? Because the migrations ran fine in development environment. The project also runs correctly. The issue is when I try to run the migrations in test environment

Comment: @Neha it seems that your test database is quite old and have some old tables that are no longer in schema so try to create new test database and then try again.

Comment: ok i'll check that. Thanks

Comment: @wasipeer I checked and the table for which it is throwing error is present. Then why couldn't it can find it

Comment: @Neha did it works with new database?

Comment: @Neha : If you are using inheritance with Active Record and don't want a class to be considered as part of the STI hierarchy, you must set this to true. self.abstract_class = true “means you
can inherit from it (the model) without using STI.”

Answer (score 0):

Are you working on multiple `tenants` with different databases and switching them using `establish_connection` method?

Perhaps from mater database to child client database, if you grant access to any table, it will work but if you miss then it can such a kind of error. (I experienced also)

You need to check inside `rails c` by `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.includes? 'articles'` which must return true.